# Python / Django - Organizing Stylesheets and Scripts

Tags: python, django, django-templates, stylesheet

I am looking for a simple way to organize stylesheets and scripts in Django.  I am relatively new to the framework and language of python.  I'm coming from a PHP background.

In the world of PHP / Zend there are functions that are implemented with the view/layout object.  By including a single line inside your head tag for scripts and for stylsheets you can easily add a stylesheet/script in the view -> method level.  I have read the Django Form Media Documentation, but this only pertains to forms needing specific styles and scripts.

Any direction?

Answer (score 5):

Look at the django.contrib.admin application.

Parallel the way the admin site works.

1. Create a media directory.
2. Create media/img, media/jss, media/css, media/whatever directories
3. In each of these, you'll have your app's specific stuff.  media/img/app1, media/jss/app1 so that each of your Django apps can have specific media without conflict or problems.
4. Be sure that your settings have the MEDIA_ROOT set.  You'll want to read about this in the Django docs.  You'll also have to set your MEDIA_URL for deployment.  And you'll have to figure out how to make your webserver (i.e., Apache) serve this media.

Django should not be serving static files like .js libraries or .css files or any images.  It's a waste of time.  Apache can serve this just fine.  For testing purposes, however, you can enable a simple file server capability in your Django site.

Finally.  And most importantly.

Be sure that your page template actually references the various files you want to include on your page `{{MEDIA_URL}}css/site.css`, and `{{MEDIA_URL}}js/app1/something.js`.

Comment: A spin-off could be `myapp/css, myapp/js, myapp/images`, `myotherapp/css, ...`. I wouldn't necessarily do it for project-specific apps, unless each app on it's own had a lot of private static resources, but I'd definitely do that for redistributable applications. That's more of how I look at the admin media: `{{MEDIA_URL}}admin/`, redistributable media that doesn't clash with existing media resources.

Comment: Be aware that the newest django (1.3beta) has contrib.staticfiles, which uses a slightly different method of organising statics. I'd have a look at that, if I were you.

Comment: @Matthew Schinckel: That sounds like a great separate answer.  Please post that as an answer so it can be upvoted properly.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that as of django 1.3, the old staticfiles app has become part of `django.contrib`.

The main thing to know is that you can stick your static media in a `static/` subdir in any app that is in your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`, and that file will be automatically collected by the `collectstatic` management command.

Rather than re-hash, I'll just point you at the docmentation: [Django: the staticfiles app](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/).

You might also want to consider looking for something that will process your text-based static files (css and javascript), which can easily be combined, minified and versioned. I'm about to look hard into this, so no links yet.

Answer (score 0):

I like to have style-related images close to my stylesheets, and a different path for user uploaded content like profile pictures, photos, videos...

So I end-up with something like this:

```
/media
    /style
        base.css
        img/
            logo.gif
            button.gif
    /js
        home.js
    /profile
         user_profile_image.gif
```

This way, image references inside css can be always relative like:

```
background: url(img/background.gif)
```

Also, there are some apps for handling media, css / js compression, sprites, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might actually looking for a way to conditionally include a stylesheet based on the current page. This can be done using template tags.

In your base.html file you would create a section to add stylesheets.

```
{% block addl_styles %}{% endblock %}
```

Then in the page you want to load the styles you would use the same block along with `block.super` to append your script to any other scripts called by your application.

So in your form's template you would use code like the following:

```
{% block addl_styles %}
{{ block.super }}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}your_css_folder/example.css" />
{% endblock %}
```

Please note that you can programmatically add the base dir using `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` and arrive at your folder in a safe manner.